# nginx image_filter resize and convert images to webp

Tags: nginx, resize, webp, responsive-images

I want to serve resized and converted png/jpg/jpeg images through image_filter in nginx to serve images in webp format. Is there any options to do so via try_files to rewrite path or another way without installing other extensions to nginx?

```
set $width "-";
      
if ($arg_w != '') { 
    set $width $arg_w; 
}

location ^~ /common/images/\.*\.(png|jpeg|jpg) {
    add_header X-Nginx-Image Resized;
    image_filter resize $width -;
    expires 12M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Comment: There is a [Serving WebP & AVIF images with Nginx](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2021-webp-avif-nginx) blog post suggesting some creative scripts to perform batch conversion of images. However nginx configuration isn't the author's strong side, more optimal configuration can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70012309/7121513).

Comment: I've found a solution for me, that works well. So, if I have converted image in webp, it resizes and server, otherwise, it resizes my base image without converting.
      set $width "-";
      
        if ($arg_w != '') { 
         set $width $arg_w; 
        }
      
        location  ~* "^(?<path>.+)\.(png|jpeg|jpg)$" {
           try_files $path$webp_ext $path$file_ext =404;
                add_header X-Nginx-Image Resized;
                image_filter resize $width -;
    expires 12M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    
    
   }

Answer (score 1):

I have organized the comments to make them look neat.

[ Source: Andrei Musteata ]

I've found a solution for me, that works well.

So, if I have converted image in webp, it resizes and serve, otherwise, it resizes my base image without converting.

```
set $width "-"; 

if ($arg_w != '') { 
    set $width $arg_w; 
}

location ~* "^(?<path>.+)\.(png|jpeg|jpg)$" { 
    try_files $path$webp_ext $path$file_ext =404; 
    add_header X-Nginx-Image Resized; 
    image_filter resize $width -; 
    expires 12M; 
    add_header Cache-Control "public"; 
}
```